# bigquery java client delete statements, sql queries

Tags: java, google-bigquery

I am using java client for bigquery. I am trying to delete few records from a table. I haven't come across any straightforward API to achieve the same. Insert/InserAll, deleting complete dataset API I am aware of.

Basically, how do we delete records from bigquery using java client API. Also, if someone can point to a better docs of Java client, it will be life saver.

how to execute this statement

```
delete from dataset.tablename where somecondtion;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can work on this code snippet to delete records from BigQuery using Java client API:

```
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQuery;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryOptions;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.QueryJobConfiguration;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.TableId;

public class DeleteRecords {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    // TODO(developer): Replace these variables before running the sample.
    String projectId = "your-project-id";
    String datasetName = "my_dataset";
    String tableName = "my_table";
    String filterCondition = "somecondition";

    BigQuery bigquery = BigQueryOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
    QueryJobConfiguration queryConfig =
        QueryJobConfiguration.newBuilder(
                String.format(
                    "DELETE FROM `%s.%s.%s` WHERE %s",
                    projectId, datasetName, tableName, filterCondition))
            .build();

    bigquery.query(queryConfig);
  }
}
```

For documentation on Big Query and Java, you may refer [here](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/bigquery/Bigquery.Tables.Delete.html?ssp=1&darkschemeovr=1&setlang=en-PH&safesearch=moderate).